# Eliminate strange grey trapezoid in transparent toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I could not find the source of some kind of mask laying over my transparent toolbar:

[image]

Does anybody know how to remove this?

When doing orientation change to landscape it's even more ugly.

Some code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"    <-- makes no difference
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_transparent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

toolbar_transparent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    style="?attr/actionBarStyle"
    android:background="#204CAF50"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.ColoredToolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

themes.xml (I admit it is a mess - much like try-and-error)

```
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase"/>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00000000</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.ColoredToolbar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` wrapper.

When I remove it and just leave the Toolbar, the trapezoids are gone.

```
<!--<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent">-->

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_transparent"/>

<!--</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->
```

Works at least for Lollipop and Marshmallow. Kitkat and below not tested yet.

BTW I'm using `com.android.support:design:24.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in styles

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this unfortunately doesn't work for me. The toolbar is not transparent. When I add `   android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to AppBarLayout, the toolbar is transparent, but it has the ugly trapezoid.

Comment: I had the same issue, but when I've added  app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay.Transparent" in Toolbar and AppBarLayout, the trapezoid is gone.

Comment: Already had this. OMG I tried so many different things. It would be helpful to know from which style or component the trapezoid is coming. The Layout Inspector doesn't tell me.